# Parameterization of URL address depending on build profile by webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, package.json

Is it possible to parametrization URL depending on webpack build profile? I'm talking about URL for services to get data from API. For example, I have in my Angular2 app:

part of *package.json*:

```
    "scripts": {
        "build-prod": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
        "build-dev": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --bail" 
    },
```

part of *webpack.dev.js*:

```
output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
```

part of *webpack.prod.js*:

```
output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
```

and part of exemplary *exampleService.ts*:

```
API_URL = "some/address/for/me";

get(url: string): Promise<T> {
        return this.http.get(this.API_URL)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {//someCode})
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

It's work fine. But if i will build app with *dev* profile i want the application ask my Apiary (for example), not my localhost. Where i should change my webpack.dev.js?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpack [`define-plugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) performs search and replace on basis of the source code. Use constants like `PRODUCTION` or the [npm de-facto standard `process.env.NODE_ENV`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#node-environment-variable) in `exampleService.ts` to chose the API URL to use.

Apply the `define-plugin` in your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  /*...*/
  plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
};
```

I recommend reading the webpack guide on [building for production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/).

NB: I think using the plugin on the `API_URL` string `some/address/for/me` might work as well: `new webpack.DefinePlugin({'some/address/for/me` might': JSON.stringify('other/url')})`